# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory'

Tags: spring, hibernate, sessionfactory

I am using spring and hibernate for configuration with mysql db.

My we.xml file has following code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/classes/applicationcontext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

My applicationcontext.xml file has following imports :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN"
"http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
<beans default-autowire="autodetect">
  <import resource="spring-config/spring-common-applicationContext.xml"/>
  <import resource="spring-config/spring-db-applicationContext.xml"/>
  <import resource="spring-config/spring-dao-applicationContext.xml"/>
  <import resource="spring-config/spring-processor-applicationContext.xml"/>
  <import resource="spring-config/spring-security-processor-applicationContext.xml"/>
  <import resource="spring-config/spring-service-applicationContext.xml"/>
  <import resource="spring-config/spring-security-service-applicationContext.xml"/>
</beans>
```

My spring-db-applicationContext.xml has following code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN"
"http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
<beans default-autowire="autodetect">

<!-- Hibernate session factory -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <constructor-arg index="0">
            <value>${driverClassName}</value>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg index="1">
            <value>${url}</value>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg index="2">
            <value>${username}</value>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg index="3">
            <value>${password}</value>
        </constructor-arg>

    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref bean="sessionFactory"/>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSource"/>
        </property>
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>WEB-INF/classes/hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property  name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <!--<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>-->
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref bean="sessionFactory"/>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionInterceptor" class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor">
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
        <property name="transactionAttributeSource">
            <value> com.sufalam.mailserver.business.service.IUserProcessor.*=PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,-java.lang.Exception
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>
 </beans>
```

I have included appropriate lib. Now at the time of running the project, i am getting following error :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in URL [jndi:/localhost/MailServerV2/WEB-INF/classes/spring-config/spring-db-applicationContext.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'eventListeners': : Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in URL [jndi:/localhost/MailServerV2/WEB-INF/classes/spring-config/spring-db-applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': FactoryBean which is currently in creation returned null from getObject; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in URL [jndi:/localhost/MailServerV2/WEB-INF/classes/spring-config/spring-db-applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': FactoryBean which is currently in creation returned null from getObject
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireByType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1141)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1034)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:289)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:286)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:188)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:526)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:730)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:387)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:270)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3934)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4429)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:526)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:630)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:556)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:491)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1206)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:314)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:722)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:583)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in URL [jndi:/localhost/MailServerV2/WEB-INF/classes/spring-config/spring-db-applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': FactoryBean which is currently in creation returned null from getObject
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1299)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1061)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:289)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:286)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:188)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:807)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:735)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:666)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireByType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1126)
        ... 37 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': FactoryBean which is currently in creation returned null from getObject
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:157)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:109)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1397)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:243)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:188)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
        ... 50 more
```

Can anybody have any solutions, why my sessionFactory bean is giving error ?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Spring is telling you exactly what the problem is, you just have to read the log and nested error message:

> Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: 
>   **Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': FactoryBean which is currently in creation returned null from getObject**

A bit of Google searching suggests that this error message is usually the result of [a circular dependency](http://forum.springsource.org/archive/index.php/t-38038.html), and also led to [a mailing list post that recommends](http://www.mail-archive.com/user@struts.apache.org/msg64147.html) removing `default-autowire="detect"` from your `<beans>` element.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply.. Actually i have already done google searching on that and i got the solution also.. But i was doing something wrong in deploying my project in tomcat.. So, i didn't know the changes is applying or not... Now i have solve this problem with your given solutions only... Thanks a lot.

Comment: The first link in the answer point to another forum thread on forum.springframework.org, which was moved to the forum.spring.io domain. The correct link to the solution of the circular dependency problem is: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/32496-circular-dependency