# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException in a MVC webapp using Spring and Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, model-view-controller

I have been trying to resolve the issue on my own since 2 days now but can't figure out the solution... I tried referring to those 2 questions but it has not been helpful. I am missing something:
[org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572067/problem-creating-bean-of-sessionfactory-in-spring-hibernate-configuration)
[Spring MVC and Hibernate configurations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9932585/spring-mvc-and-hibernate-configurations)

I have followed this tutorial to create a simple Spring MVC + Hibernate web app using Maven: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2010/11/spring3-mvc-hibernate-maven-tutorial-eclipse-example.html
I didn't have any issue using maven or importing the libs with the pom.xml. I can deploy the war that I created with Maven properly.

Edit:
**As pointed in the answers to my questions, I did not declare the commons-collections dependency. After adding it, this is the exception I am getting:**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contactController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private net.viralpatel.contact.service.ContactService net.viralpatel.contact.controller.ContactController.contactService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contactServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private net.viralpatel.contact.dao.ContactDAO net.viralpatel.contact.service.ContactServiceImpl.contactDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contactDAOImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory net.viralpatel.contact.dao.ContactDAOImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'configurationClass' of bean class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean]: Bean property 'configurationClass' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
```

**Note: If I delete the property below:**

```
<property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
```

**Then I have a 404 error after deploying the application in tomcat.**

Here is the servlet-spring.xml as it is right now:

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="net.viralpatel.contact" />

    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
        p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}"
        p:password="${jdbc.password}" />


    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>


</beans>
```

Comment: you don't need `configurationClass` in session factory properties

Comment: mixing words like spring, hibernate and simple in one sentence is your first mistake. Try grails to simplify.

Comment: if I take off configuration class, maven is building the war properly, the deployment in tomcat goes fine, nothing in the logs, but when I am trying to access the app, I got a 404 error. I double checked putting back the configuration Class, and I end up having again a Invalid property 'configurationClass' of bean class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean]: Bean property 'configurationClass' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?

Comment: @dukable exactly same problem with the same example. Please let me know if you find out any solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/CursorableLinkedList

Add [`commons-collection.jar`](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/commons-collections/commons-collections/1.0/commons-collections-1.0.jar) to your class path

There is no such property in [`HibernateTransactionManager`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/HibernateTransactionManager.html), Just remove

```
<property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
</property>
```

Comment: Thank you, I got rid of this exception, however I still have as mentioned on the bellow comment an exception saying that configurationClass is not writable. If I take it off as suggested, then I can't access my web app after deployment in tomcat (404).